# GetComponent returning null randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get all colliders of game objects with a layer mask "Zombie Layer" with a certain radius using Physics.OverlapSphere.

My problem is sometimes the code works and sometimes the I get this error below when I try to get the Zombie AI script component. I've ensured that all my zombie game objects have the ZombieAI script attached to them.

[image: error]

Here is the code:

```
public class SoundDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float soundIntensity = 10f;
    public LayerMask zombieLayer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Detect();
        }
    }

    private void Detect()
    {

        Collider[] zombies = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, soundIntensity, zombieLayer);

        if (zombies.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < zombies.Length; i++)
            {
                zombies[i].GetComponent<ZombieAI>().OnAware(); //error here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The above code is in a different script placed in my fps controller. If I remove this script and attach it again, the code works until it stops randomly for some reason.

I tried looking at other solutions but couldn't figure anything out since I'm still new to Unity 3D.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answer in the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1260204) is pretty much a "how to troubleshoot a NRE", a guidebook if you will. Use the advice in that answer to figure out what is causing the NRE in your code

Comment: Like I said, I've seen that solution and it didn't solve my issue. My problem is I have the ZombieAI script component attached and GetComponent<>() is still returning null.

Comment: Please also unmark my question as a duplicate as that question has nothing to do with Unity I believe.

Comment: Is `zombies[i].GetComponent<ZombieAI>()` returning `null` or is `zombies[i]` returning `null`?

Comment: Then you have to figure out *why* is that item returning `null`. You can do that by stepping into the code at run time with your debugger attached.

Comment: See also the [documentation Collider.GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), returning `null` is an expected possible result. You need to check for it in your code. You can do that with a check or make the subsequent call using the elvis operator ?. if you do not want to do anything if the result is null.

Comment: Finally, the duplicate question is applicable here as well.

Comment: zombies[i].GetComponent<ZombieAI>() returns null. On checking for Zombies[i], for some reason it's returning my bullet prefab

Comment: Okay, so somehow, my bullet prefab's layer mask was set to Zombie Layer. That's why its crashing because that prefab does not have a zombie AI script. I don't know why I didn't do a log for Zombies[i] too. Thanks, @Igor :)